# Asynchronous read/write multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, io, task-parallel-library

We are building a custom CMS in which we have to overwrite the content of multiple HTML files(around 1000) on server through my admin panel in one go. I am new to asynchronous and parallel programming So after some R&D I decide to use Parallel programming (TPL) for my problem and below is sample code I am using to overwrite the files with some text.

Now the problem is I have to read the multiple files too in parallel, in my example I am using a simple  variable string text = "In file " + index.ToString(), but in actual each file which is being overwritten will be replaced by a static template(for each page) and some dynamic values(for CMS elements) from database. I don't understand how to do this multiple read/write for multiple files in parallel :

```
    static async void ProcessWriteMultAsync()
    {
        string folder = @"E:\test\";
        string[] items = { "Site1", "Site2", "Site3", "Site4", "Site5", "Site6", "Site7", "Site8", "Site9", "Site10", "Site11", "Site12", "Site13", "Site14",
        "Site15","Site16","Site17","Site18","Site19","Site20",};
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        List<FileStream> sourceStreams = new List<FileStream>();

        try
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < items.Length; index++)
            {
                string text = "In file " + index.ToString();

                string filePath = folder + items[index] + "\\ProcurementTemplate.html";

                byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

                FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                    bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);

                Task theTask = sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
                sourceStreams.Add(sourceStream);

                tasks.Add(theTask);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        finally
        {
            foreach (FileStream sourceStream in sourceStreams)
            {
                sourceStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, pull the logic to write a file into a method:

```
async Task Write(string text, string filePath) {
                byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

                using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath)) {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
 }
}
```

Then use [Stephen Toubs `ForEachAsync`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) to process all items. You need to experimentally determine the right degree of parallelism. It certainly will not be 1000 as it is now in your code. The right DOP depends on the IO system and on how much data the OS buffers.

```
items.ForEachAsync(async (item) => await Write(item, GetPath(...)), dop: 8);
```

The old code basically works but it is quite low level and verbose.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem, just for your info my server is a 16 core machine. Your point is valid that my code is not for 1000 right now. Also what you mean by "The old code basically works but it is quite low level and verbose" it means my code or something else. How can I read/write simultaneously as I have to load the template file and hit database 1000 times to load the values in it.

Comment: Yes, old means yours. I don't understand the question in your comment. My answer demonstrates how to do something simultaneously in an async way. Is this not helping you?

Comment: My question is that text parameter in write method will contain some values from database, So if I have 1000 files then it means I have to call database 1000 times. So is it possible to achieve this asynchronously as it seems like I have to call Write function one by one for each file.

Comment: You can query the database once before invoking the `items.ForEachAsync...` line. You can also call it from within `Write`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Then it means I have to call it 1000 times synchronously right, only write will be asynchronous.

Comment: If you call it from **within** `Write` you can conveniently call it asynchronously using `await`. You can call it where and however you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117334/discussion-between-chupchapcharli-and-usr).

Comment: ok, so you means if my database calling code is inside Write then its all asynchronous.Also what about creating 1000 different tasks for each read/write?

Comment: This is precisely why I'm using ForEachAsync. It will *not* create 1000 tasks. I have configured it with a DOP of 8.; Whether the DB access is sync or async depends on how you write it. You can write it sync or async.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it but my main question is same that by putting DB access code inside Write method how it  will make my code asynchronous as to connect db I don't have any method like WriteAsync()

Comment: It does not matter whether you make those db calls sync or async. ForEachAsync will run your method 8 times in parallel. The DB code is always parallelized regardless of the call style. Your question does not show any database code so it's a bit hard to see what you mean. Maybe you just need to try doing it?

Comment: @Tomas A simple way is to make the tasks write their own results into a list. Need to synchronize access to that list.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an array of tasks - one for each file - and then run them all using `Task.WaitAll`:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync(string text, string file)
{
    using(FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> fileNames = new string[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt" };
Task[] writingTasks = fileNames
                          .Select(fileName => DoWorkAsync("some text", fileName))
                          .ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(writingTasks);
```

Comment: This starts N concurrent tasks. When the item number is in the thousands this not the right way to run IO.

Comment: @waldemar: Thanks for replying but what about when "some text" will be read from database and is different for each file.